# AngularJs UI Router : Prevent view from reloading when switching tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angularJs UI routing to create tabs in my application.

I have multiple tabs in my application and each tab has various input fields.

> The user can switch tabs while filling the fields in one tab while
>   doing this the data in the previous tab is lost as the controller for
>   the tab is reloaded each time it is opened.

How to avoid reloading the view contents so that I can retain the selected tab and all the contents as-is before switching the tab.

Comment: are the tabs child of their parent?

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcwhvp

Comment: Thank you Prashant, but my code is in angularjs . Do you know how to do it in angularjs.

Comment: No the tabs are not children, they are seperate components.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at dynamic parameters:

https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/2.0.1/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#dynamic

That allows for changing the router parameters without reloading the route. I use that for tabs, and it works for me.

Another option is to not keep any data in the component. Put it in a service, and it will persist between route changes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am fairly new to angularjs , can you show how to use the params declaration mentioned above.